# Ansible to Open Terminal and Run Program on Remote Ubuntu Machine

Tags: ssh, ansible, ubuntu-18.04, gnome-terminal

I'm using Ansible to setup an instance of Ubuntu 18.04 (remote) and run certain programs within the user environment.  I have a command I'd like to execute inside a terminal on the remote that requires the terminal stay open.

If I'm on Ubuntu and run the following command I get exactly what I expect.

```
# DISPLAY=:0 nohup gnome-terminal -- roscore
```

1. Use the current display for the user
2. nohup so the terminal won't close if the parent terminal closes
3. start a new gnome-terminal instance
4. --  = run a command inside the new gnome-terminal instance
5. roscore can be replaced by any command that requires an open stream to a terminal window

My Ansible task looks like this when trying to recreate the same command

```
- name: Start terminal on remote machine
  shell:
  args:
    cmd: DISPLAY=:0 nohup gnome-terminal -- roscore
    executable: /bin/bash
```

When running this command I get the following verbose output

```
changed: [] => {
"changed": true,
"cmd": "DISPLAY=:0 nohup gnome-terminal -- roscore",
"delta": "0:00:00.243119",
"end": "",
"invocation": {
    "module_args": {
        "_raw_params": "DISPLAY=:0 nohup gnome-terminal -- roscore",
        "_uses_shell": true,
        "argv": null,
        "chdir": null,
        "creates": null,
        "executable": "/bin/bash",
        "removes": null,
        "stdin": null,
        "stdin_add_newline": true,
        "strip_empty_ends": true,
        "warn": true
    }
},
"rc": 0,
"start": "",
"stderr": "nohup: ignoring input",
"stderr_lines": [
    "nohup: ignoring input"
],
"stdout": "",
"stdout_lines": []
}
```

When I execute this it appears that the terminal is opened for just a moment on the remote machine but it does not stay open.  What is Ansible doing that would close the remote terminal session after running the command?

What I want is an Ansible task that will allow a terminal window to open on a remote Ubuntu 18.04 machine. Stretch goal would be to get the command running in the now open terminal.

Any help would be appreciated and glad to clarify where needed.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I've decided to go a different direction but wanted to post what I learned.

To execute a command from Ansible that will open a terminal window on the Ubuntu 18.04 (remote) machine will require the following command:

```
- name: Start terminal on remote machine
  shell:
  args:
    cmd: DISPLAY=:0 nohup gnome-terminal </dev/null >/dev/null 2>&1 &
    executable: /bin/bash
```

Notice the `</dev/null >/dev/null 2>&1 &`.  This is necessary for Ansible to be able to disown the process while allowing the terminal to remain open on the remote machine.

**In Theory**, I haven't proven this but to run a command inside the terminal would require an extra gnome-terminal argument `-e`.

```
-e, --command=STRING
             Execute the argument to this option inside the terminal.
```

**Example**

```
- name: Start terminal on remote machine
  shell:
  args:
    cmd: DISPLAY=:0 nohup gnome-terminal -e "bash -c 'whoami'" </dev/null >/dev/null 2>&1 &
    executable: /bin/bash
```